# how to inherit methods from abstract class properly

Tags: java, inheritance

I have `abstract class Animal` and a few subclasses like `Wolf`, `Rabbit` and so on. All methods are in Animal class, for example method move(). All animals virtually the same, but they have different properties, which are stored in variables. For example, method move() use variable int speed.

So, hierarchy looks like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public int speed;

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Went " + speed + " tiles");
    }
}
```

```
public class Wolf extends Animal {
    public int speed = 5;
     
    public void move(){
        super.move();
    }
}
```

When method move() called from object of Wolf class (wolf02.move()), I want it to use properties of concrete class, but it tries to use variables of class Animal, where they all non-initialized.

How to make it right?

Comment: **Remove** `public int speed = 5;` from `Wolf`. Add an empty constructor to `Wolf`. Set `speed = 5` there. Do not redeclare `speed`. That will ***shadow*** `Animal.speed` -- and there's no need to add a `move()` implementation that does nothing but invoke `super.move()` so you can remove `move()` too.

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic, you can't *override* them.